# MVC reading subobjects right after Create

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with foreign keys.
I can successfully reference the child object in my Details view with

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CHILD.CHILDNAME)
```

But I can't read the subobject after I create a new parent.

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PARENTID,CHILDID")] PARENT pARENT)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.PARENTs.Add(pARENT);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.CHILDID = new SelectList(db.CHILDs, "CHILDID", "CHILDNAME");

    int childid=pARENT.CHILDID;  //this works
            string childname=pARENT.CHILD.CHILDNAME;  //this returns null
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(pARENT);
    }
```

How do I make it so I can reference the CHILDNAME right after I create my new Parent record?

My guess is that it has something to do with the model not linking the dependent tables until the data is saved and reloaded--but I thought the Viewbag call might take care of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the parent object gets saved, the subobjects won't be automatically loaded with that save.  You will need to reload the parent object to access those subobjects.

Comment: Can I reload the parent object in the Create function?  I want to send an email with some of the child information before it hits the next page.  How do I do this?

Comment: Sure.  After the SaveChanges, just requery the DB ensuring that you are including the subobjects in that query and you should have your data.

Comment: I'm using pure MVC, not doing direct database sql querying.  So based on your suggestion, I tried:
db.PARENTs.Add(pARENT);
                db.SaveChanges();
                pARENT = db.PARENTs.Find(pARENT.PARENTID);
                ViewBag.CHILDID = new SelectList(db.CHILDs, "CHILDID", "CHILDNAME");

--doing a find after the save. but this didn't work.  can you send sample code to reload the record?

Comment: I don't know your exact model, but it would be something like  pARENT = db.PARENTs.Where(a => a.PARENTID == pARENT.PARENTID).Include(a => a.CHILD).FirstOrDefault();